# Unity audio import settings for android

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine, import

I'm creating simple game in unity and recently I bought some audio clips on assetstore. Some of them are quite big so i searched about import settings for audio and found [this](http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/wrong-import-settings-killing-unity-game-part-2/). My problem is that I'm building game for android and I don't know which things(like CPU or RAM) are more important for optimization (for android). Do you have any Idea what should I do?

Comment: Usually CPU is more important. CPU makes sure everything runs smoothly without hiccups while usually there is loads of RUM to be spared ))

Comment: @NikaKasradze So from what  I understand best choice for android is using “Compressed In Memory” and “Vorbis”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universal rule for choosing **Load Type**. The catch is that all the sounds need to get decompressed at some point to get played. Compressed 3 megabyte .mp3 file can become 32mb or more. Set **Compression Format** on **PCM** and you'll see how much space will it take when decompressed. See **Imported Size** on this image:

[image]

On this image I'm working with .mp3 file which grows from 0.6mb to 7mb on decompression.

**Note:** this was just a showcase. In fact if you set your **Compression Format** to PCM the sound will get decompressed on compile-time and **Load Type** is useless in this case (Unity really should gray it out in this case). But decompressed audio will make the game size bigger.

So, in absolute majority of cases **Compression Format** is applied (currently only option is **Vorbis**, Unity may add some more though). Assuming you use compression you should consider if you are willing to sacrifice RAM to get better performance or other way around.

Back to **Load Type**: For example, if I was to ship my 0.6mb mp3 file to iOS/Android game I would probably set it on **Decompress On Load** because frame-rate is #1 priority on mobile. I'd need to save CPU cycles during gameplay so I'd try to load sound in menu. But if this was a PC game I'd probably use **Compressed In Memory** so that it gets decompressed chunk by chunk while playing.

So basically this setting is really for a post-production/optimization. If you're getting **Did Receive Memory Warning**'s a lot than you'd go for **Compressed In Memory**. But if you're struggling for maintaining a decent FPS than you'd rather set it on **Decompress On Load**.

Comment: Wait I don't get it. You said that "Decompress On Load because frame-rate is #1 priority on mobile" and then "But if you're struggling for maintaining a decent FPS than you'd rather set it on Compressed In Memory". So Decompress on Load is good for keeping good FPS on mobile?

Comment: ups, sorry, I totally messed it up at the end. The last paragraph should be other way around. Fixed it thanks :D